# How to show an uploaded image which is outside the webapp's deploy folder?

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat

I have successfully uploaded an image to "C:\Images\ProfilePic\prImage.jpg" which is outside the  webapp's deploy folder . Uploading works fine. But i have trouble in displaying the uploaded image. i have added

```
<Context docBase="C:\Images" path="/Images" />
```

to Tomcat's /conf/server.xml .

I used

```
<img src="/Images/ProfilePic/prImage.jpg" />
```

to display it, but its not working at all. Help me..

Comment: In html you cant refer to to a location on the filesystem outside your webapp (it is logical if you think about it). What you can do is to make a file server page that serves the images to the webpage. You then use the file server page as src in your image tags.

Comment: i know we cant refer to a location outside webapp thats why i tried <Context docBase="C:\Images" path="/Images" />, can i achieve it using this,...??

Comment: Do you consider context path and servlet path when you want to address it from the browser. user a URL like this in your browser and see what happens : `http://localhost:port/context-path/servlet-path/Images/ProfilePic/prImage.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that this way.

If you want to store some files and let user see them with a URL from browser, you should write a file servlet and get the name and relative path of the file and then read the file in the servlet and flush it to be displayed in browser.

There is a grate tutorial and sample code [here by balusc](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html)